# Range Indexes MarkLogic

Tags: indexing, marklogic

After creating a range index for an element, does one have to use element-range-queries to reap the benefits ? or do Xpaths with inequality predicates also reap the the benefits ?

For example: 
Will the below Xpath expression use range indexes ?

```
/info/employee[dob gt "1990-01-01"]/name
```

Answer (score 2):

The optimizer will always look for possibilities to leverage indexes and lexicons, but whether it is able may depend on subtleties of how you wrote your code. Functions like `xdmp:plan` are usually good tools to discovering whether MarkLogic was or wasn't able to do so.

XPath does dictate that results are ordered by document order, and your expression selects `name` descendants within documents. Both will always involve filtering. A `cts:search` call would allow running unfiltered with potentially better performance results.

HTH!